# mysql | Request with checking by time from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**1. Users**

```
id last_check
1  2014-10-30 19:24:16
```

**2. Stream**

```
id date                
1  2014-10-30 19:22:16
2  2014-10-30 19:23:16
3  2014-10-30 19:24:16
4  2014-10-30 19:25:16
5  2014-10-30 19:26:16
```

I would like a query to count stream where stream date > last_check date. In the example above count will be 4 and 5. Thanks!

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Stream WHERE date > (SELECT last_check FROM Users LIMIT 1)
```